# Пример использования REST API

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. Хочу создать Android клиент для сайта. У сайта есть API. 
Но я не совсем понимаю как отправить из приложения запрос, для получения данных с сервера.

Например, мне нужно получить данные о пользователе с **ID = 100** . Перейдя по ссылке `http://api.my_site.com/us.php?id=100` выводится на страницу следующее:

```
id = 100;
nick = Admin;
balans = 20;
status = online;
```

Так вот, как мне отправить запрос к такой странице из приложения и как вывести только `nick` и `status` на экран.

Буду благодарен за любую информацию которая сможет мне помочь.

**Обновление**

Для наглядного примера.

```
{"coord":{"lon":32,"lat":46.97},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"ясно","icon":"01d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":23,"pressure":1024,"humidity":27,"temp_min":23,"temp_max":23},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":5,"deg":60},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1441886400,"sys":{"type":1,"id":7365,"message":0.0071,"country":"UA","sunrise":1441855387,"sunset":1441901633},"id":700569,"name":"Mykolayiv","cod":200}
```

Comment: в каком виде выводит то? надеюсь не в таком же как вы привели

Comment: ну в таком случае норм

Comment: Это JSON и для него должно быть полно всего.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для запроса можно использовать [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). А дальше парсить ответ. В вашем случае видимо разбивать строку по `\n` и каждую строку по (пробел). Но если вы разрабатываете сайте переделайте возращаемый результат в JSON. Потом будет проще.

Если же вы уже возвращаете JSON то для работы в ним(и xml) рекомендую использовать [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) в частности [этот класс](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). Очень упрощает жизнь.

Пример работы с `HttpURLConnection` можно посмотреть [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html). Это простой вариант, вообще этот класс поддерживает запросы через все HTTP Method(GET, POST and etc.) и много чего еще(теже куки).

Comment: можно где нибудь увидеть пример кода отправки запроса?

Comment: @Денис можете посмотреть тут - http://devcolibri.com/1486

Answer (score 5):

Для работы с REST api лучше всего подойдет использование уже готовых библиотек, таких как [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), Volley и т.д.

Типичный пример взаимодействия с REST сервером с использованием библиотеки Retrofit выглядит так:

1. Определяем интерфейс, в котором описываем методы, которые предоставляет сервер

```
public interface SomeRestApi {

    @GET("/some/endpoint/")
    SomeResponce execSomeMethod();
}
```

2. Конструируем объект для взаимодействия с сервером(для Retorofit версии 2)

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://base.url")
    .build();
SomeRestApi api = retrofit.create(SomeRestApi.class)
```

3. Обращаемся к серверу

```
SomeResponce responce = api.execSomeMethod();
```

При получении ответа от сервера Retrofit автоматически преобразует его ваш объект `SomeResponce`. Однако поля в `SomeResponce` должны иметь либо имена, такие же как в JSON ответе, либо поля должны иметь аннотацию `@SerializedName("name")`.

Например если JSON ответ от сервера имеет следующую структуру

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "field": "qwerty"    
}
```

то объект `SomeResponce` должен иметь следующую структуру

```
 public class SomeResponce {

    public int id;

    @SerializedName("field")
    public String someField;

 }
```

тогда Retrofit автоматически преобразует ответ от сервера в ваш объект.

Retorift поддерживает синхронное и асинхронное выполнение запросов, передачу параметров в запрос, заголовки и многое другое. Более подробно можно узнать на [официальном сайте](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) или в [презентации Jake Wharton'a](https://speakerdeck.com/jakewharton/simple-http-with-retrofit-2-droidcon-nyc-2015)